Ruby Case statements and pinning, does not work with attr_reader
This code works:
class Hello
  def initialize
    @name = "Paul"
  end

  def say_name(maybe_name)
    name = self.name
    case maybe_name
    in ^name
      puts "Hello, Paul!"
    else
      puts "No match"
    end
  end

  private

  attr_reader :name
end

Hello.new.say_name("Paul") # "Hello, Paul!"

However if I remove name = self.name, I get a no local variable name for the pinned variable.
Is this a bug in Ruby, or the intention? I suppose it only works with local variables? If I remove this line, name is nil inside the say_hello method, but it is defined.

try in ^(name)


Is this a bug in Ruby, or the intention?

That specific error is intentional. When referencing a local variable that doesn't exist, you get an exception.

I suppose it only works with local variables?

It works with any kind of variable, as mentioned in the docs: "you can also pin instance, global, and class variables". However, the plain ^variable syntax doesn't work with methods. To get your code working, you have to either reference the instance variable @name directly:
case maybe_name
in ^@name
  # ...
end

or use the ^(expression) syntax which allows to "pin the result of arbitrary expressions using parentheses": (with the "arbitrary expression" being a method call)
case maybe_name
in ^(name)
  # ...
end


It does work with arbitrary expressions. Just have to wrap in parentheses.

Ah it doesn't work with methods, that's what threw me. I suppose I'm used to thinking of methods and variables as effectively interchangeable in Ruby, since we don't think about types as much as in other languages.

Honestly, I'm not sure why pinning requires parentheses in the first place in order to allow arbitrary expressions. ^expression looks perfectly fine to me but they probably had their reasons ;)

@Stefan I would assume it is because of things like operators, chained method calls, method calls with arguments, etc. For example I agree I don't mind ^expression but the following are less appealing ^1 + 1, ^expression.downcase, ^expression.select {|i| i < some_calculation}. In these cases the explicit parens not only differentiate the logic but almost certainly make for a more streamlined parser.

@engineersmnky there are certainly (many) use cases where parentheses are necessary. I'm just surprised that a plain ^name doesn't simply evaluate name. Limiting that lookup to just variables doesn't seem to make much sense to me.
